# Disabling folder creation in sitecollection SharePoint online

Tags: site-collection, folder

Is it possible to disable folder creation for the whole site collection instead of only on library?

Answer (score 2):

Actually **No**, Since Folder creation is a feature of List/Library; So you can not do this at site level.
But there is an **alternative way do achieve the same**. You can run a power-shell script which will loop through all the List/Library based on your selected Template. there you can set property

> EnableFolderCreation to false

below is the sample code for your reference:

```
$sites = Get-SPSite 'http://<site name>' | Get-SPWeb -Limit All
#Get list of document libraries in the farm and remove system folders from the list
$folders = $sites.folders | where {($_.name -ne "FormServerTemplates") -and ($_.name -ne "Style Library") -and ($_.name -ne "SiteAssets")}

#Get a list of document librarys that are actual document libraries and not catalogs etc...
$items = $folders.properties | where {$_.vti_listservertemplate -eq "101" }
$libs = $items.vti_listtitle 
$itemsclean = $libs | select -Unique

#Run through the list of libraries
foreach($i in $itemsclean){    
    $list = $sites.lists | where title -eq $i
    $list.EnableFolderCreation = $false
    $list.Update()    
}
```

**Edit:** For SP Online using CSOM code

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://your-site-url"); 
Web web = clientContext.Web;
ListCollection listColl = web.Lists;
foreach(List lst in listColl)
{
    if(lst.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary"){
        lst.EnableFolderCreation = false;
        lst.Update();
    }
}
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: This is for SharePoint Online so the above would need to be converted into CSOM code, but in theory yes the correct approach.

Comment: Ahh, Thanks for pointing out. I have updated my answer

Comment: @j.Cup.. see this famous CSOM+Powershell introduction for SP Online-- http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/12/Using-CSOM-in-PowerShell-scripts-with-Office365.html

Comment: This is the first time i am going to use powershell for the company. I in stalled SharePoint online management shell and did the following on the beginning: `$adminUPN="aaaaaa"
$orgName="xxxxxx"
$userCredential = Get-Credential -UserName $adminUPN -Message "Type the password."
Connect-SPOService -Url https://$orgName-admin.sharepoint.com -Credential $userCredential`
After this i am supposed to immediately add your code? Is there a tutorial somewhere so i don't have to ask the basic things?

Comment: Please see my comment above for tutorial reference

Comment: I seems to remember that even when the option to create folders has been set to No, the users will still be able to create folders when accessing the libraries using "open in Windows Explorer",  pretty annoying actually